# How to catch mailgun errors in laravel

Tags: laravel, email, mailgun, laravel-5.5

I have mailgun set up and working just fine. The problem occurs when I try to send an email to an email which doesn't exists. Use can put any email so if the email is correct mailgun sends it perfectly. But if it is incorrect it generates an error in laravel applications

```
 Swift_TransportException (554)
 Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 Free 
 accounts are for test purposes only. Please upgrade or add the address to 
 authorized recipients in Account Settings.
```

How can I catcth this exception in laravel without generating errors?